# add / show x more comments and add comment links showing together

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, web-sockets

I'm seeing this quite often now, where I'll view a post with a number of comments (not always a lot) and both links are visible and stay there. Clicking on either one doesn't remove the other.

Not sure what causes it; it happens intermittently, possibly when someone posts a comment as I'm loading, or after loading the page.
Usually reloading the page fixes it.
It started happening after the web socket stuff got implemented I think.

I know this isn't much to go on, but thought I'd log it anyway.

Comment: Do you have [this userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/2051/reply-links-on-comments) installed, by any chance?

Comment: Yes I do. I can't actually remember the last time I used it. Removed!

Comment: Ah, that was probably it then. It creates a clone of that link in a way that'd usually be invisible to the user, but because the WebSocket event code is looking for the original link it's possible for them both to be displayed when a notification of a new comment comes in.

Comment: I've updated the script with a fix. That link cloning @TimStone mentions was a crappy workaround that was necessary because back in the days when I wrote that script, I had no idea what I was doing.

Comment: @balpha: Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The userscript:  ["Reply" links on comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2051/reply-links-on-comments) has been shown to cause this issue. Hopefully I can get balpha to update his userscript when he returns from his honeymoon.